What Video format to use to support transparent video on Web applications, for Desktop and Mobile, that supports all browsers (desktop and mobile)
I have a web application build on NextJS. I intend to use a transparent video, which currently I have as MOV and WEBP, WEBP works absolutely fine on Chrome (Desktop), while MOV works fine on Safari (Desktop). But I am facing issues when it come to Chrome (IOS), Chrome (Android) has no issues. However Chrome (IOS) does not show the alpha channels, it shows a while background. How can I fix this? what is the best approach for this, or is there any other file type that I should use?

I remember from a while ago when trying to implement something like this, there isn't universal alpha channel support. The best way I could do it is by masking two videos (the B/W mask for alpha and the video itself) in a canvas, using some globalCompositeOperation.

Can you elaborate further?

I made a script that plays two videos simultaneously, print the Black and White ('alpha') version to the canvas using composite operations to define what pixels to show, then a second pass to fill them with the expected color. Dont have the time to explain or write an answer regarding that but if you're interested I could get to that.

Use the WebM format along with the VP9 codec and alpha channel to enable translucent video on desktop and mobile web applications. Most contemporary browsers support this format.
Use VP9 and an alpha channel to export your video in WebM format (for example, in Adobe After Effects).
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="your-video-file.webm" type="video/webm">
    <img src="your-fallback-image.gif" alt="Fallback image">
</video>

Use the WebM format along with the VP9 codec and alpha channel to enable translucent video on desktop and mobile web applications. Most contemporary browsers support this format.
Use VP9 and an alpha channel to export your video in WebM format (for example, in Adobe After Effects).

No this wont sort my issue, since I have already tried this, and as I mentioned in my question it works, but not on ios chrome or safari mobile only.

After researching further I identified the issue in this approach, this approach works fine, but if it is causing issues only on ios (chrome/safari) its because the mov needs to be encoded to HEVC with transparency.

Yeah you right , it causing issue only on iOS for this

There are multiple approaches to this.
The first option is to use a different video format. You speak of using webP, but have a look at VP9/WebM. Have a look at its possible implementation. Google itself also speaks on the uses and shortcomings of webP.
As a second option, as some commenters already mentioned, one way is to have two videos. One being the mask and one to have the colors. For that, you can see the following example that uses the HTML canvas.
Important Note: Please click the 'full page' button to properly see the snippet in action. Else, scroll down after pressing p to play.
Credit: Nathan Searles


const width = 640;
const height = 450;
let videoPlaying = false;
let processControl;

// Main video
const canvas_video = document.getElementById('canvas_video');
const video_ctx = canvas_video.getContext('2d');
const video = document.getElementById('video');
video.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
video_ctx.canvas.width = width;
video_ctx.canvas.height = height;

// Mask
const canvas_mask = document.getElementById('canvas_mask');
const mask_ctx = canvas_mask.getContext('2d');
const mask = document.getElementById('mask');
mask.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
mask_ctx.canvas.width = width;
mask_ctx.canvas.height = height;

// Output canvas
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const output_ctx = output.getContext('2d');
output_ctx.canvas.width = width;
output_ctx.canvas.height = height;
output.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

function Process() {
  processControl = window.requestAnimationFrame(Process);

  video_ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
  mask_ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, width, height);

  // getImageData
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData
  const image = video_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  const imageData = image.data;

  const maskData = mask_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

  for (let i = 3, len = imageData.length; i < len; i = i + 4) {
    imageData[i] = maskData[i-1];
  }

  output_ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 80){
    if (videoPlaying) {
      mask.pause();
      video.pause();
      videoPlaying = false;
      cancelAnimationFrame(processControl);
    } else {
      mask.play();
      video.play();
      Process();
      videoPlaying = true;
    }
  }
}
/*
  Background pattern:
  https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/
*/
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #5353;
  background-image: background-color: #ee5522;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 200 200'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='a' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='100' y1='33' x2='100' y2='-3'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23000' stop-opacity='1'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='b' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='100' y1='135' x2='100' y2='97'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23000' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23000' stop-opacity='1'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg fill='%23d23d09' fill-opacity='0.6'%3E%3Crect x='100' width='100' height='100'/%3E%3Crect y='100' width='100' height='100'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg fill-opacity='0.5'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='url(%23a)' points='100 30 0 0 200 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='url(%23b)' points='100 100 0 130 0 100 200 100 200 130'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  display: none;
}

#output {
  display: block;
  margin: 80px auto;
}

video {
  width: 640px;
  height: auto;
}
<div id="stage">
  <p id="control">Hit "p" to play/pause videos</p>

  <!-- Main element -->
  <canvas id="output"></canvas>

  <!-- Shown for reference -->
  <canvas id="canvas_video"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas_mask"></canvas>

  <!-- Hidden with CSS -->
  <video id="mask" src="http://nathansearles.com/videos/knife-mask.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" loop></video>
  <video id="video" src="http://nathansearles.com/videos/knife.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" loop></video>
</div>




Let me try this. This seems to be very promising compared to the solutions I have seen before.

I have tried this, but unfortunately the video seems to have a very bad quality in this way. my original video is in hd. but this isn't. How to make it possible for my video to look exactly as the same quality of the original video

Did you make sure to adjust the height and width in the code to the resolution of your video? Afterwards, you can use scaling to change it, but lets first check if the resolution is the problem?

I used the other approach which is I used Webm video. It worked perfectly alright. Although it had a twist. I had to encode the mov to ensure it works on safari and chrome ios. And the webm worked perfectly fine on chrome Mac OS and windows.
